Is there a way to insert a default field to each user's 'wincon' model or lock the form field to a value based on another form field?
I am building a game tracker. I would like to have it where if the user selects anything other than 'Win' then the wincon field of the form is unchangeable or set to a default field. This is to make it easier to understand that when they don't win they shouldn't add a wincon. It would also be nice if the user had a blank field that if they didn't want to input a wincon then it would default to '------'
Ideally if it is a win then the wincon field would be able to be changed.
But if a loss is selected then the form defaults to null or a prepopulated field like '------'
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=10,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Wincon(models.Model):
    wincon = models.CharField(max_length=100,)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=10,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.wincon

class Game(models.Model):
    # ForeignKeys
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=10,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)
    wincon = models.ForeignKey(Wincon,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,)

views.py
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def wincon(request):
    wincon_list = Wincon.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        wincon_form = WinconForm(request.POST)
        if wincon_form.is_valid():
            obj = wincon_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/wincon')
    else:
        wincon_form = WinconForm()

    context = {'wincon_form': wincon_form, 'wincon_list': wincon_list, 'user': user}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/wincon.html', context=context)

forms.py
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set wincon list shown to only wincon from user
        user_wincon = Wincon.objects.filter(user=user)
        user_wincon_list = []
        for wincon in user_wincon:
            user_wincon_list.append((wincon.id, wincon.wincon))
        self.fields['wincon'].choices = user_wincon_list

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = {'date', 'time', 'user'}
        labels = {
            'num_players': '# of Players',
            'start_pos': 'Starting position',
            'mull': 'Starting hand',
            'outcome': 'Outcome',
            'wincon': 'Your Wincon',
        }

In my forms.py I tried to add a default wincon like below
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set wincon list shown to only wincon from user
        user_wincon = Wincon.objects.filter(user=user)
        user_wincon_list = [(0, '------')]
        for wincon in user_wincon:
            user_wincon_list.append((wincon.id, wincon.wincon))
        self.fields['wincon'].choices = user_wincon_list

But that just creates a default of '------' and if left selected then the form throws an error of
"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the avaiable choices."
